# html input box on android has a green highlight on tap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, html-input

we have a phonegap app for android.

on android 4.1.1 on a HTC device we have the following problem:

when tapped an input box gets a green highlighting. however the actual problem is that you tap a box, but the box below gets highlighted. but then again the tapped box gets focus.

we have tried to removed it but -webkit-tap-highlight-color or outline did not solve the issue.

Comment: We're running into a similar issue with an HTC One X running 4.1.1. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: not yet, please let me know if you find any

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* make transparent link selection, adjust last value opacity 0 to 1.0 */
}

body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;                /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;             /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
    -webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
    /*background-color:#E4E4E4;*/
}
```

Comment: add this meta tag   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">